# CURL login by script to a Joomla website

Tags: php, curl, authentication, joomla

I need to login by a PHP script that uses CURL to a Joomla website, in order to access to a private page that needs to be processed, but nothwithstanding several attempts I have done, I have always a 403 error. I have done a similar thing with other websites and it worked.

Script I use:

```
$uname = "id";
$upswd = "pswd";
$url = "http://www.somewebpage.com";
$agent = "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.6) Gecko/20060728 Firefox/1.5.0.6'";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url1);

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['passwd'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['remember'] = 'yes';
$postfields['option'] = 'login';
$postfields['op2'] = 'login';
$postfields['return'] = urlencode($url);
$postfields['message'] = '0';
$postfields['force_session'] = '1';
$postfields['j3b00d36f4336137f4f03335c5eee6440'] = '1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

The username and password, as well as the website URL I am using are perfectly working.

This is the result I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2010 08:29:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.7a DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Is there something wrong in my CURL request? Or is there a limit with Joomla remote login?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified PHP translation of Paul Sweeney's answer. It works in Joomla 1.5 :)

```
$uname = "id";
$upswd = "pswd";
$url = "http://www.somewebpage.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)) {
    preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
}

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['passwd'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['lang'] = '';
$postfields['option'] = 'com_login';
$postfields['task'] = 'login';
$postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: need to declare `$spoof` ?

Comment: you might think so, but PHP creates the variable if it's not declared. Look at php manual examples, they all look like `preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)` with $matches undeclared

Answer (score 2):

You have several probelms here..

firstly you are using the wrong fields. 
option="com_user" not "login"
task="login"
(am asuming you are talking about joomla 1.5, not joomla 1.0 , they are different)

but the biggest problem you have is that joomla puts a unique tag in every form, and that value can only be used once. so that means that a login form can only be submitted once, it cant be stolen and replayed like you are trying to do. (even if it is not for a nefarious process)

so you would have to request the joomla login page, scrape the form values, then resubmit the data.

alternatively you could create a plugin that does what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for explanation. About the fields (like option=login), they are exactly those in the original login form. I will try as you suggest. I do not know which version of Joomla is used

Answer (score 2):

You know, I wrote something really similar this week to do some testing on our Joomla install. The trick is to make two requests to the site: one to fetch a unique login token, and create a user session, and another to actually log in.

You gotta share the cookie across both requests, and each new request user session will generate a new token, I believe.

Here's my script in bash, using wget:

```
function login {
    Server=$1
    User=$2
    Pass=$3
    Token=`wget \
        --quiet \
        --load-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --save-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --keep-session-cookies \
        --output-document=- \
        "http://${Server}/administrator" | \
    grep -Po '"[a-zA-z0-9]{32}"' | \
    grep -o "[^'\"]*"`

    wget \
        --quiet \
        --load-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --save-cookies ~/cookies.${User}.txt \
        --keep-session-cookies \
        --output-document=/dev/null \
        --post-data="username=${User}&passwd=${Pass}&option=com_login&task=login&${Token}=1" \
        "http://${Server}/administrator/index.php?option=com_login"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ login www.google.com "username" "password"
```

You could probably translate this to curl in PHP, or just use a straight exec() call if you're on a *nix system, and not too concerned about security. (Putting code that requires exec() into production, is a good way to get your SysAdmin or CM worked up).

Answer (score 1):

Using yitwail's php code, I tried http://demo.joomla.org/1.5/ with the username / pass demo / demo, created a mydomain.com/yitwails_php_script.php and ran it.  Shouldn't I be able to go to the joomla demo now, and already be logged in?  It does not seem to work that way - am I missing something in the process?

Comment: I tried the same and it did not go through.  Anyone have the answer on this?

Answer (score 0):

The cURL request seems fine in on itself. It might be a problem on the server's side rather than within your request - there could be a messed up .htaccess file, or invalid permissions for files on there, which only manifest during such "automated" login attempts.

Comment: As I understand, you do not have access to the server's logs to see what error it produces?