# Calling Joomla Authentication plugin to login user in a page outside of joomla?

Tags: authentication, joomla

I have a page outside joomla, but i am using joomla framework, i need to import system Authentication plugin to login a user manually. How do I call system auth plugin and manually login a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it 2 ways - by loading the Joomla framework on to the page so you have access to create the necessary token, or you can use cURL to create the session and submit the login remotely. Here's the code for the cURL method: [Logging In To Joomla 1.5 Using External Form (not within joomla folder, but on same server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-sa/5207806#5207806)