# Joomla - Logging in a Guest User by Script

Tags: curl, joomla1.5

**UPDATE:**
I found an IIS bug that might be causing the problem. See this post [IIS and nph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565535/non-parsed-headers-in-php).

_________________Original Question_______________________________________________________________________________

I have a Guest Joomla user that has access to a less private, but still private, part of my website. I want some users, accessing by a special link containing a hash, to be able to login automatically under the limited access Guest account.

To accomplish this, I'm following a post by Brent Friar [Logging in using cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-sa/5207806#5207806).

Parts of the process are working.

- I am able to make the cURL request, scrape the token value.
- Once the script runs, I can look at the Joomla session table and see an entry for my guest user.
- When I print the value of the cookie just before I set it - it matches the cookie in the session table.

However, when I try to proceed to the area of the site the Guest user should have access to, I get redirected to the login screen. When I inspect the cookies in my browser, it's not the same cookie that printed in the script. Then if I check the session table again, I see that the new cookie is tied to a newer, anonymous session.

Why is the cookie set in setCookie() not persisting?

**Here is my code:**

```
$uname = "DocGuest";
        $upswd = "pass";

        //This is the URL of the normal login form on the website
        $url = "http://localhost/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=115&Itemid=283";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
        $ret = curl_exec($ch);
        if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)) {
            preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
        }

        $postfields = array();
        $postfields['username'] = $uname;
        $postfields['passwd'] = $upswd;
        $postfields['lang'] = 'en';

        $postfields['option'] = 'com_user';
        $postfields['task'] = 'login';
        $postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        $ret = curl_exec($ch);


        // Get logged in cookie and pass it to the browser
        preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $ret, $m);
        $cookie=explode('=',$m[1]);
        print_r($cookie);  //Cookie matches session table here?


        //header("location:  http://localhost/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&Itemid=158");
        setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1], 3600*24, '/');
```

Comment: @Brent Friar - I'm casting the bat signal to you, Brent Friar :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, interesting issue, I will assume that you are using XAMPP due to the domain. First thing I see that could cause a problem is the redirect being before you transfer the cookie.

```
//header("location:  http://localhost/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&Itemid=158");
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1], 3600*24, '/');
```

Should be:

```
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1], 3600*24, '/');
header("location:  http://localhost/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&Itemid=158");
```

The other thing I would do is not set the path to the cookie. I know in the past I have had issues with XAMPP paths not working like I thought they would. Try using:

```
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1], 3600*24);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time - I updated my question. I'm actually on IIS7 to match the production environment (I know, I'd rather be on LAMP). As for the Header/cookie order. I thought so too, but it turns out that the webserver shouldn't care about the order. Also, on the setCookie page in the PHP docs - about 10 comments down, there is a post mentioning that the redirect should come first. Tried both..