# Non Parsed Headers in PHP

Tags: php, iis

There is an IIS bug that causes problems with headers when using a CGI program, and setting a redirect to a page that returns a http 302 (Object Moved). The result is that IIS doesn't parse the headers, so if you're trying to set cookies, it's not going to work. See the [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q176113/)

It says the solution is to start the EXE CGI with -nph (Non parsed Headers) - but I'm not really sure if it works in PHP. I tried adding it to my php file and manually building headers, but that didn't work for me..

Has anyone had this problem? Any good workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixing the PHP file with nph-, not -nph - solved this issue for me.

```
e.g. nph-test.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how you're seeing this bug in the modern era.

First, Q17..., er, I mean, KB176113 was published in **1997**.  The examples list **IIS 2.0** as the product affected, and the article itself claims *only* versions 3-5 are affected.  Unless you're running your site on *Windows 2000*, you aren't using IIS5.  Both the article and a bit of time in Google suggests that this problem is entirely fixed in IIS6 and later.

Second, the bug impacts only CGI scripts.  If you are using PHP with IIS, then you are either using the ISAPI DLL (and if you are, I'm *so* sorry), or you're using FastCGI, which despite having three letters in common, is not actually CGI.  Nobody has run PHP in CGI mode on IIS since...

You *aren't* using IIS5, are you?

Okay, if you aren't on IIS7, you might not be running in FastCGI mode.  [You should totally switch to FastCGI](http://www.iis.net/download/fastcgi) with modern PHP versions.  Microsoft spent a lot of time and effort getting PHP and FastCGI playing nicely with IIS.

Third, setting cookies mid-redirect has been buggy in every browser on every platform at one time or another.  Are you sure that the cookie header isn't actually being sent?  Check your browser's development tools.

Comment: I am running FastCGI and this is still an issue. If you have something stating otherwise, I'd love to see it. prefixing the related PHP file with nph- (e.g. nph-test.php) solved the issue for me. I can recreate the issue, on IIS 6 & 7, running PHP under FastCGI.

Comment: @cinqoTimo, this implies that the knowledgebase article is incorrect, and you should consider contacting MS.