# Log into Joomla without visiting the Joomla install on PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, joomla

I have Joomla installed as a new folder under an existing domain that already has a PHP/MySQL authentication system.  I have also tied all the users in the old system to the Joomla users.

What would be the simplest way to execute Joomla login once a user successfully enters their user name and password for the old system?

I am looking for something along the lines of:

User puts in name / pass on mysite.com and hits login
mysite.com pulls their info from the DB and successfully authenticates
Now, I want to call some function logUserIntoJommlaToo(username, password); because I already have their correct name and pass for Joomla as well.

Bonus points, keep their Joomla session alive while they browse the old site, and of course a lot out counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

To login from a remote system - [Logging In To Joomla 1.5 Using External Form (not within joomla folder, but on same server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-sa/5207806#5207806)

One of the options in the Joomla login module is the Remember Me checkbox. That will keep your login active until you log out. Simply pass that parameter along with the username and password in the code above.

Logging out should be possible through cURL as well or you could just delete the Joomla cookie.