# Can Joomla site use an external site for sign on?

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to setup a "Single sign on" environment, where one of the sites is a Joomla site. I want all logins to happen at an external site (not the Joomla site).

The Joomla site does have some guest access. I'm having a problem when the guest on the Joomla site clicks a link that requires them to be logged in. Joomla automatically redirects to it's own login page when I want it to go to an external page.

Is there an existing plugin that can redirect to a custom, external login page? Or, is there a Joomla function that can be overridden to intercept the login redirect?

*Basically, I want to override what happens in /includes/application.php - method "Authorize"*

Comment: please list what your Single Signon method is? MS Active Directory? Open ID?  Other...?  Should we be guessing? Or giving you an answer like "yes it is possible".

Comment: @ Jakub - The real question is in the 2nd & 3rd paragraph, not the first. It's custom SSO, meaning, I want credentials from one site to sign in users on multiple other sites (Really, the type of SSO is irrelevant to the question). If you want to continue guessing, that's fine - or you can read the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You can do it through cURL, details here -

[Logging In To Joomla 1.5 Using External Form (not within joomla folder, but on same server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-sa/5207806#5207806)

In order to get the users to an external login page when Joomla tries to send the user to it's own login page, I would use a simple redirect in htaccess.

If you are not using SEF URLs then the redirect will need to look something like this -

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_user(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=login(&|$)
RewriteRule ^$ http://mySSOsite.com? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Brent. I've already got the signing in aspect taken care of (in part, thanks to your post). What I can't figure out, is if a guest user on the joomla site tries to go to a private page - how do I get Joomla to redirect to the external login URL? Right now, I hacked the "authorize" method in /includes/application.php. However, I was looking to do this without a core hack..

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I misunderstood the intent. I'll update my answer.

Comment: +1 for the good idea. I'll see if I can figure out how to accomplish that - will post results back..

Comment: I tried 'Redirect /index.php?option=com_user&view=login 'htttp://mySSOsite.com' - (it's actually 'http', was getting formatted as link) but it didn't work. I'm on Windows, that could be a problem, or perhaps because the login page isn't a physical path..?

Comment: Any time that you have a query string the redirect is a little different. It takes a few lines, editing my answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 1.5 comes with plugins for LDAP, OpenID and Gmail authentication. 
The plugins can be configured in the Joomla backend (Extensions > Plugin Manager). If you do not use any of these authentication methods you might check out the plugin code to create a new one fitting your needs.

Comment: This is custom SSO -- not Windows AD, or Gmail. I need the system to redirect to an external URL before login (There are lots of plugins for controlling what happens after login). An authentication plugin isn't really what I'm looking for.