# Joomla PHPmaker authentication

Tags: authentication, joomla2.5

I have already created my webpage with PHPmaker. An now I have install Joomla for my Homepage. Now My client has two username and password to login with this PHPmaker and Joomla created webpage.

I want to creat a plugin for joomla as when my user login to the joomla it automatically login the PHHmaker webpage too. So that my client can login the two website with a single login page.

Please guide me.

Note :- Joomla authentication for PHPmaker webpage.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Save yourself a ton of trouble and just put the whole website in Joomla. Creating a bridge to login to both is not a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In case you REALLY want to do it this way, you can get details on how to build the remote Joomla login portion here -

[Logging In To Joomla 1.5 Using External Form (not within joomla folder, but on same server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-s/5207806#5207806)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. and sorry for my less explaination in my question. I am very new to the programming. I was planing to make a bridge to login both joomla and PHPmakwer website. As soon as my client login to the joomla page it should also automatically authenticate the PHPmaker website so that my client can use all the feature in PHPmaker website by login the joomla website.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't need PHPmaker at all. The whole point of Joomla is that the client never has to touch any code, that's your job. They should only have to enter the content.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass login credentials to PHPMaker via script and this will create session which you can use in Joomla too or else if you have used UserTrack settings then your user session data will get stored in user table into Usertrack field you could validate your user details and use Usertrack field and use that.

Kindly let me know whether that worked for you.