# Joomla sessions for login

Tags: rest, curl, joomla, session-cookies

I have a Joomla website. I have coded a component that allows a user to login using a REST based service call. For example:

```
http://abc.com/rest/login/greg/greg
```

When this is executed on a browser, the credentials are checked using JAuthentication and the
user is logged in like this:

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$usersipass['username'] = $name;
$usersipass['password'] = $password;
$mainframe->login($usersipass);
```

However, this all works if I check in the same browser I executed the URL. To allow this to happen from an external agent like the command line does not work:

```
curl -v http://abc.com/rest/login/greg/greg
```

Obviously, this has something to do with setting the correct cookie in the browser in question. I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207806/1965699) stackoverflow question that allows a user to login using an external php curl script. The part about cookies goes something like this:

```
// Get logged in cookie and pass it to the browser
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $ret, $m);
$cookie=explode('=',$m[1]);
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1]);
```

However, this does not log the user in the same browser. Authentication works in all cases. My end goal would be to call the REST API from a javascript framework like Meteor and get the user logged in the same browser.