# How to use web services to share Joomla login session from one website to another?

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, soap, joomla

This is file which is use to login on joomla site.

```
// a super-stripped down 2-leg oauth server/client example
function getLogin($userid, $psswrd) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    jimport('joomla.user.authentication');
    jimport('joomla.session.session');
    $auth = &JAuthentication::getInstance();
    $session = &JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('name', "value");
    $ssn_name = $session->get('name');
    $sessionDetails = array(
            'State' => $session->getState(),
            'Expire' => session->getExpire(),
            'Token' => $session->getToken(),
            'FormToken' => $session->getFormToken(),
            'Name' => $session->getName(),
            'Id' => $session->getId(),
            'getStores' => $session->getStores(),
            'isNew' => $session->isNew());

    $username = $userid;
    $password = $psswrd;
    $credentials = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password);
    $options = array();
    $response = $auth->authenticate($credentials, $options);

    if ($response->status == JAUTHENTICATE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        $response->status = true;

        $sessionDetails['loginStatus'] = $loginStatus = $app->login($credentials, $options);

        return $sessionDetails;
    }
    else {
        $response->status = false;
        return 'testFalse';
    }
}
```

Now we are calling this using localhost by

```
$client = new nusoap_client("http://domain-name/site-name/nusoap/remoteLogin.php");

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $client->call("getLogin", array(
        "userid" => "admin",
        "password" => "test"));
```

After this session is created at above project and update it in database with new entry. But still not login on site.
Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Authentication and login are two different steps. You need to authenticate first, which you are doing. Then you need to do the login work. Look at the Joomla user plugin.

Comment: But in first code i  have authenticate and then login . But its not working from another server file which is 2nd code file.code-1 is for site for which i have to login from remote site. code-2 for remote site.

Comment: Are you doing everything else the the Joomla user plugin is doing https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/user/joomla/joomla.php#L172? I don't think so, for example i don't don't see you putting the data into the session, which is something that the plugin does.  Or are you using the joomla plugin?

Comment: please have a look to this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176142/logging-in-to-joomla-1-5-using-external-form-not-within-joomla-folder-but-on-s/5207806#5207806

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Devjohn please check my url you can test your local simple how to soap access remote.

you can find here my bolg to you problem i think it may help you

`http://phptechnicalgroups.blogspot.in/2012/10/json-return-using-soap-server-and-soap.html`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as Brent Friar posted and elin cited, you need to

- Create a new session and get the associated token
- Pass the username, password, and token to create a logged in session
- Get the new cookie values for logged in session
- Transfer cookie to the browser

Here is the code needed to accomplish all of this:

```
<?php
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$upswd = $_POST['password'];
$url = "http://joomla website.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('./cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
if (!preg_match('/name="([a-zA-z0-9]{32})"/', $ret, $spoof)) {
    preg_match("/name='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $ret, $spoof);
}

// POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['username'] = urlencode($uname);
$postfields['passwd'] = urlencode($upswd);
$postfields['option'] = 'com_user';
$postfields['task'] = 'login';
$postfields[$spoof[1]] = '1';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

// Get logged in cookie and pass it to the browser
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', $ret, $m);
$cookie=explode('=',$m[1]);
setcookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1]);
?>
```

This should work on any Joomla website as long as the URL used in the script has a login form on the page. Once you run this script you should then be able to access the website and be logged in.