# curl probing of web sessions

Tags: curl

Kind of a "newbie question", to partially confirm/correct my understanding:
I want to implement some automated Website probing incl. logging on, I don't want to actually pull any data. From an earlier job I remembered curl and for just checking URL availability (eval HTTP response code, e.g. 200 or not) this works nicely.
Now the task is logging on as well - but I cannot get it to work and have some doubts whether this works at all as intended. After experimenting a while and searching through the WWW I could not find a explicit answer - so my hopes are here :-)

Originally my idea was to use a script and just put in the curl POST command inside, just in case with the cookies options, e.g.:

```
$ curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -o /tmp/tge-HTML.out -b /tmp/tge-cookies -c /tmp/tge-cookies -F "username=bla&passwd=blub&Submit=Login" http://some.url
```

(I used HTTPfox to determine the POST parameters and am mostly certain to have them right)

Then I search through the file /tmp/tge-HTML.out whether it contains "Logout" as a proof that I have logged on (even if not logged on, I always get HTTP 200 in all the tests with the various URLs I tried).

In one of the cases (with a Tomcat behind) I see that, after logging on in Firefox, the subsequent URLs contain ...&jsessionid=... which, of course, I initially don't know - so I tried a couple of things, e.g. to call curl (the command!) twice in a shell script, get the sessionID from the first and append it to the second URL, like:

```
 $ curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -o /tmp/tge-HTML.out -b /tmp/tge-cookies -c /tmp/tge-cookies -F "username=bla&passwd=blub&Submit=Login" http://some.url
 ... extract jsessionid from /tmp/tge-HTML.out ...
 $ curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -o /tmp/tge-HTML.out -b /tmp/tge-cookies -c /tmp/tge-cookies 
    http://some.url/...?jsessionid=...
```

But whatever I tried, I never got anywhere :-|
Now the questions:

1. If I do a curl-based POST as in the example above, do I
   (usually?) get the complete HTML page as response just as I see it
   in a regular web browser after logging in?

   - looks to me as if true, but then a simple POST should do and it should contain the "Logout" ...
   - however, since I never get this to work, what might be wrong?
2. If I must do multiple HTTP requests, does
   that concept of using the curl command like that work at all? What
   happens when curl exits? The socket closes and the web server
   probably closes the session (and my jsessionid is invalid)?

   - If this approach does not work, a libcurl-based concept might work better? E.g. phpcurl (just read about it but never tried yet) where I keep the session within my php script, hence connection/session remains open etc ...
   - Possibly depends on whether the site uses cookies or not?
3. Are there better ideas how to accomplish the
   original idea? Ideally it should be simple with some scripting but
   no huge Monitoring suites

Most likely there are many "depends ..." :-| Also, possibly the questions are not 100% precise, but any hints are appreciated!! :-)

Rgds,
  tge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally I made some progress - maybe it helps other people ...
First, the script-based approach does work, at least in one of the test cases with a Joomla at the server-side (I'll try the others later). Key to the solution was this:
[CURL login by script to a Joomla website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212557/curl-login-by-script-to-a-joomla-website)

Similar to the described way I extract the token from the response of the first GET and put it into the form parameters of the second:

```
rm -f /tmp/tge-cookies
HTTP_CODE=$(./curl -s -w "%{http_code}\\n" -o /tmp/tge-HTML-out.1 -b /tmp/tge-cookies -c /tmp/tge-cookies -L ${URL})
# Eval HTTP_CODE ...
Token=`awk '{ if(match($1, "<input") && match($3, "name=\"[a-z0-9]+\""))
  {
    gsub("name=\"", "", $3);
    gsub("\"", "", $3);
    if(length($3) == 33)
    {
      print $3;
      exit 0;
    }
  } }' /tmp/tge-HTML-out.1`
HTTP_CODE=$(./curl -L -s -w "%{http_code}\\n" -o /tmp/tge-HTML-out.2 -b /tmp/tge-cookies -c /tmp/tge-cookies -d "username=${User}&passwd=${Pass}&option=login&task=login&${Token}=1&remember=yes&Submit=Login" ${URL})
# Eval HTTP_CODE ...
# Eval /tmp/tge-HTML-out.2 whether containing "Logout" ...
```

The second difference is that using "-F" does not work but "-d" does.
Quite interesting is that the POST parameters differ from what I see in HTTPfox.

Regards
  tge