# Login into Joomla website using another website

Tags: php, post, authentication, joomla

I have developed a joomla website. I also have a PHP based website.

Let's call my joomla website to be `www.xyzjoomla.com` and my PHP based static website to be `www.myPHPwebsite.com`

I have created a login form on `www.myPHPwebsite.com` and want to login into `www.xyzjoomla.com`.

The idea behind is that when we submit a form in joomla, some data is being send to the page (some `$_POST` values) and joomla takes those credentials and logs in. So my query is that, is it possible to send those data from `www.myPHPwebsite.com` to `www.xyzjoomla.com` so that when data is received by the joomla site from that PHP site it logs user in.

Or if this is not possible, then is there any alternate to achieve this thing.

Comment: What is the purpose of using site X to log in to site Y? This is mildly nonsensical.

Comment: not sure which file(s) exactly but you will need to include the joomla library

Comment: @Lodder To include the joomla library? How... It can be called in a non joomla website?

Comment: @Matt This makes sense man, because I have a parent site based on PHP and one child site based on Joomla, and want to users to login from both the website into joomla. So it makes sense if you can help, It would be so nice. Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible. Sessions are site-specific and client-specific, man.

Comment: @Matt thanks, I got this point. So is there any way to achieve it, or any Joomla way to accomplish it?

Comment: No. There is no way to achieve it. I thought I made that clear when I wrote "It's not possible."

Comment: @Matt Ok, thanks for the help and definitely to enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a login on your php site the problem becomes very similar to single sign on and  you could use one of the SSO systems available. Jfusion comes to mind here.

http://www.jfusion.org/

Or build a simple login on the parent and use jfusion or similar to SSO between the sites.

Comment: but jfusion only works with other CMS based softwares.... as what i was reading, is there any way i can get it work with my own PHP based website?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You'd have to use cURL. Since Joomla uses a unique id for their forms, you'll have a little uphill battle, but it's possible.

The trick is scraping the page first, and logging in second.

You can see more info here [CURL login by script to a Joomla website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212557/curl-login-by-script-to-a-joomla-website)