# CURL login to joomla not working

Tags: php, curl, joomla

I am trying to login in a joomla site from my website using curl, but I failed each time.
here is my code:

```
$useragent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Alexa Toolbar; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urltojm); //$urltojm is url of joomla login page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=admin&passwd=".$password); //$password is my password
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "COOKIE.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "COOKIE.txt"); 
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
echo $buffer;
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: `echo curl_error($ch);` before `curl_exec()`. What does it output?

Comment: it is not getting any error

Comment: @Masum Nishat Please do not suggest edits that changes the original code in the question.

Comment: i have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212557/curl-login-by-script-to-a-joomla-website this but this is not useful to me

Comment: Debug a `$buffer` like `var_dump($buffer)` before you `echo` it. What does it say?